# Parse SDK pinInBackground callback does not return

Tags: android, parse-platform, callback

Using android and saving things client side only. The pinInBackground `SaveCallback()` is never getting to the `done(ParseException e)` method.

I followed another answerer's advice that at least one of the columns has to be different, but this also did not help me.

Comment: can you post the ParseException message ?

Comment: @ClaytonOliveira there is no ParseException because it never makes it to the `done` call back

Comment: My mistake. did you enable the datastore, calling Parse.enableLocalDatastore() in your Application class ?

Comment: @ClaytonOliveira hm yes but I was calling it before the Parse initialize function, would this be problematic?

Comment: No, this is actually right, you must call it before Parse.initialize().

Comment: @ClaytonOliveira this is a previous question I tried before posting my own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897231/saveinbackground-callback-doesnt-work , but there's isn't about pinning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81691/discussion-between-clayton-oliveira-and-cqm).

Comment: Any progress in this issue ?!

Comment: @3amoura it can take minutes to respond

Comment: The problem that it saves the data locally, why it takes all that time ?!

Comment: @3amoura I don't know. I/O operations can take a while but yes this is abnormal. You need to structure your logic differently

Answer (score 0):

Did you already figure this out? I experienced the same issue and spent the last few hours working on it. Nothing worked, so I decided to just restart my phone and did that the trick.

Comment: the callback function can take minutes to respond