# Android application - saveEventually() and saveInBackground() callback methods are not functioning

Tags: android, parse-platform

In our Android app, we are using saveEventually() and saveInBackground() of parse sdk (version 1.8.0).
It seems to work fine mostly but sometimes all calls to saveEventually and saveInBackground fail with the callback not getting called.
when this happens, we are still able to fetch data from Parse i.e. all read queries work.
We are using local storage. The updates start working again once we clear the app data.
What could be causing this?

Comment: Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897231/saveinbackground-callback-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Parse.enableLocalDatabse()` is on. I had this one before - it's hard to get to this point (it took me couple of days to figure it out). So get rid of this one in Your `Application` class and it should work.

Oh, and get latest version `1.10.3`